# Why should I set write permission to my tty in order to use the write cmd?

Tags: unix, tty

The purpose of the `write` command is to send msg to a user logged in a tty. In order for this command to work, the receiver should set write permission on his tty for the group. This is necessary since:

1. the `/dev/ttyXXX` belongs to the tty group
2. the `write` command is using SGID with the tty group to let users have a chance to write to someone's tty

Ok. Now, if the sender don't set write permission for his own tty, he can't write to someone else tty's.
I can't see any technical grounds for this! Is this just to preserve some kind of politeness? And even in this case, why does the `wall` command don't follow the same principle? Anyone can use wall while his `mesg` says n....

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The implication of write is that it is two way communication.
From the man page:

If the recipient wants to reply, this can be accomplished by
 typing a message

I don't think you would be pleased to have some other user able to spam text to your terminal without reprisal/reply from you.   Think of it as a sanity requirement.